# How to move down the div optimally?( with img being absolutely positioned)

Tags: html, css

```css
.absolute{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=244">
</div>
<div class="moveDown">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quibusdam nam vel dolore amet quis eius libero repellat ut, ipsa laboriosam dolorum alias iure reprehenderit ullam voluptas officia at iusto.
</div>
```

#---------------------------#

div.moveDown is under the image .. How to optimally position div.moveDown at the bottom of the image...

Comment: Just remove `class="absolute"`

Comment: I need that image to be absolutely positioned